# Check if an element in a list is present in multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have to check if an element in list is present in multiple list.

Example:

```
cornerCase = [-1, 4]
top = [1, 2]
bottom = [2, 3]
left = [-1, 2]
right = [3,1]
```

In this case I have to check if -1 or 4 is present in any of the elements in top, bottom, left or right lists. Looking for a solution in more pythonic way.

My attempts:

```
1. 
    check = [i for i in cornerCase if i in top or bottom or left or right]
```

Didn't work. Realized after `or` it looks for other expression.

```
2.
    check = [i for i in cornerCase if i in (top, bottom, left, right)]
```

Damn! Didn't work again. Anyone please explain why ?

```
3.
    check = [i for i in cornerCase if i in [top, bottom, left, right]]
```

Obviously didn't work because checking a element in a list of lists.

I check `if check != []` then `-1 or 4` was found in those lists.

Any good pythonic way to achieve this ?
Not looking for a solution with multiple `for` loops and individual `if` statements for all the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its just wanted to just check if `-1` or `4` is present. any builtin function in python comes handy and returns True or False. So there won't be any need of `if check != []:`

```
>>> any(item in l for item in cornerCase for l in (top, bottom, left, right))
True
```

And Drashan's solution also works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Though It may not be a very nice solution but it works simple and well,

```
check = [i for i in cornerCase if i in top + bottom + left + right]
```

Comment: Well, it works. Nice little hack by joining all the lists.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and maybe not way too pythonic) is to simple iterate over `cornerCase` and check if any of these are in any of the other lists:

```
def check(cornerCase, top, left, bottom, right):
  for i in cornerCase:
    if i in top or i in left or i in bottom or i in right:
      return true
  return false
```

Comment: Works, but I would better do this : check = [i for i in cornerCase if i in top or i in bottom or i in left or i in right]

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:
for c in cornerCase:
    if c in top or i in left or i in bottom or i in right:
        return true
    else return false

OR:
List=[top,left,right,bottom]
for c in cornerCase:
    if c in List
        return true
    else return false